# Get List of objects in django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a contact manager using Django. I've created a form with the following code:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="First name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Last name")
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, help_text="Email")
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=False, help_text="Phone")
    company = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=Company.objects.all(), required=False, help_text="Company")

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'company')
```

I'm having problems with the company field. I don't know how to pass a list of all companies to the form so it can display as a select tag in html. I believe I have to convert it to a dictionary so the "choices" argument would work, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField):

```
company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all(), required=False, help_text="Company")
```

Comment: This works too, but the solution provided by LuRsT gives you the option to use a PK so the form would pick the value of an instance if I were to use it as an editing form, which is what I really wanted. I believe I should have asked better. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Actually, after having some issues with the answer provided by LuRsT I tried again this one and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a tuple or list of 2-tuples to the `choices` kwarg.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices

Try this:

```
company = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=Company.objects.all().values_list(pk, name), required=False, help_text="Company")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: @angardi you're welcome, can you mark my answer as the solution so that the question is closed? Thanks

Comment: I've had some problems with that code, At first it seemed to work because it gave me the list and selected the correct option from the drop-down, but when I tried to save the form I got an error saying that the company I've selected didn't exist. That doesn't happen with Omid Raha answer.

Comment: Ah of course, I overlooked that you were using a ModelForm, that's why Omid's answer works and not mine since the Form is excepting a model and not a pk.